# How to install sudo and nano command in MySql docker image

Tags: mysql, django, docker

I am trying to connect Django application with MySql docker container. I am using the latest version of MySql i.e MySql 8.0 to build a container. I was able to build the MySql container successfully but I am not able to connect it using Django's default MySql Connector. When I run the `docker-compose up` command I get the error mentioned below.

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, 'Plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mariadb19/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory')
```

I started looking for the solution and got to know that MySql has released a major change in its default authentication plugin which is not support by most of the MySql Connectors.

To fix this issue I will have to set the `default-authentication-plugin` to `mysql_native_password` in `my.cnf` file of MySql container.

I logged into container using command `docker exec -it <conatiner id> /bin/bash` and was also able to locate the `my.cnf` file inside the container.

To edit the `my.cnf` file I will have to use the `nano` command as stated below.

`nano my.cnf`

But unfortunately `nano` command is not installed in MySql Container. To install `nano` I will need `sudo` installed in container.

I tried installing `sudo` using below mentioned command but it did not work.

`apt-get install sudo`

error -

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

What are the possible solutions to fix this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general you shouldn't try to directly edit files in containers.  Those changes will get lost as soon as the container is stopped and deleted; this happens extremely routinely since many Docker options can only be set at startup time, and the standard way to update the software in a container is to recreate it with a newer image.  In your case, you also can't live-edit a configuration file the main container process needs at startup time, because it will have already read the configuration file by the time you're able to edit it.

The right way to do this is to inject the modified configuration file at container startup time.  If you haven't already, get the default configuration file out of the image

```sh
docker run --rm mysql:8 cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf > my.cnf
```

and edit it, directly, on your host, using your choice of text editor.  When you launch the container, inject the modified file

```sh
docker run -v $PWD/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf ... mysql:8
```

or, in Docker Compose,

```yaml
volumes:
  - ./my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

The [Docker Hub `mysql` image documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) has some more suggestions on ways to set this; see "Using a custom MySQL configuration file" there.

While `docker exec` is an extremely useful debugging tool, it shouldn't be part of your core workflow, and I'd recommend trying to avoid it in cases like this.  (With the bind-mount approach, you can add the modified config file to your source control system and blindly `docker-compose up` like normal without knowing this detail; a `docker exec` approach you'd have to remember and repeat by hand every time you started the container stack.)

Also note that you don't need `sudo` in Docker at all.  Every context where you can run something (Dockerfiles, `docker run`, `docker exec`) has some way to explicitly specify the user ID, so you can `docker exec -u root ...`.  `sudo` generally depends on things like users having passwords and interactive prompting, which works well for administering a real Linux host but doesn't match a typical Docker environment.

Answer (score 5):

Mysql build the image with oracle linux, run the commands to install nano:

```
microdnf update
microdnf install nano sudo -y
```

And edit the my.cnf with nano

Answer (score 4):

The issue is not with **sudo** because you've already permissions to install pacakegs.
You should instead update package manager before to install new packages in order to update package repositories:

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install nano
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Docker desktop.
Go to containers, then to the database container.
Run container.
In database container, switch tab to terminal.
One of this command should work:

```
apt-get install nano
microdnf install nano sudo
```